# How to deserialize request body as child classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openapi

We have an API defined by an OpenAPI spec (v3). There is an Animal class which Cat and Dog both inherit from. When the generated C# client makes a request, say for a `List<Animal>`, they are correctly deserialized as the child classes. However, if we try to POST a `List<Animal>` containing Cats and Dogs, the generated C# ASP.NET backend only gets them as Animals instead of the child classes. When we post a Cat using Postman the backend receives an Animal, so I'm fairly sure it's a ASP.NET generation issue.

The spec.yaml is:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /saveData:
    post:
      description: Send all the data required
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: query
          required: true
          description: The id of the animal
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
            example: 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SaveData'
      responses:
        200:
          description: The animal
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Animal'
        401:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorised'
        400:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'

components:
  schemas:
    SaveData:
      type: object
      required:
        - animals
      properties:
        animals:
          type: array
          description: A list of animals
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Animal'

    Animal:
      type: object
      discriminator:
        propertyName: className
      required:
        - "id"
        - "name"
        - "className"
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          description: The unique ID of this object
          format: uuid
          example: 3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
        name:
          type: string
          description: Gives a name to the animal
          example: Bob
        className:
          type: string
          description: Determines which child class this object is
          example: Cat

    Cat:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Animal'

    Dog:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Animal'
        - type: object
          required:
            - "breed"
          properties:
            breed:
              type: string
              description: The breed of dog
              example: Terrier
              nullable: true
```

An example request body would be:

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "id": "84d40807-4c68-4b41-9c24-619847e80269",
            "name": "Bob",
            "className": "Cat"
        },
        {
            "id": "67a4b35e-4fc3-4a67-a77a-2a032640559f",
            "name": "Spot",
            "breed": "Husky",
            "className": "Dog"
        }
    ]
}
```

These both get deserialized as Animal, therefore Dog loses it's child properties.

How can we adjust the definition or generation to allow for these classes to be properly deserialized on the server side?

Comment: Post your code - the classes, the client code that makes this post, the MVC action that receives the post.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a very easy fix. The client side code generation included the `JsonSubtypes` attributes that are required for proper deserialization.

In the above example, the start of the Animal class should look like:

```
using JsonSubTypes;

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "className")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Cat), "Cat")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(Dog), "Dog")]
public partial class Animal
{
    // Class stuff here
}
```

I also had to run `dotnet add .\myproject.csproj package JsonSubTypes` to get the package.